# My screen goes black when loading youtube

Tags: 14.04, flash, screen, youtube

I'm using ubuntu 14.04. Everytime I load youtube (and some other sites that use flash) the screen goes black.

Comment: Which browser do you use?

Answer (score 1):

If you frequent a lot of flash sites, and you have no issues with using non-free software (not as in price, but as in source), you can use pepperflash with chromium.

From Software & Updates make sure that (multiverse) is enabled

[image: Software & Updates]

Launch a terminal (ctrl+alt+t)

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree
```

It will take a little bit to download the files and install. I usually keep chromium closed while installing, but I'm not sure if it is required. With pepperflash you should have no problems with flash sites on chromium.

Answer (score 0):

Type `sudo apt-get install chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra` in terminal. Restart the browser, visit any Flash contained website and check if the issue recurs. If the issue persists, leave the comment. I will try to figure out another way to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck the "use harware acceleration" button in settings. That worked for me on Chrome and Chromium.

Answer (score -1):

try this. worked for me. http://www.solveyourtech.com/turn-hardware-acceleration-google-chrome/

I'm using ubuntu 14.04. Everytime I load youtube (and some other sites that use flash) the screen goes black.